# Extract macOS release name from Darwin/XNU versions

Tags: macos, version, darwin

Is there any equation to get macOS version (10.X) from it's corresponding darwin version or xnu version (without having a pre-defined table per version)

For example, In macOS Mojave (10.14) we have the following contents :

```
darwin version 18.0.0
xnu version 4903.200.249
```

And in macOS high sierra (10.13) we have :

```
10.13.3: xnu-4570.41.2  darwin version 17.4.0   
10.13.2: xnu-4570.31.3  darwin version 17.3.0   
10.13.1: xnu-4570.20.62 darwin version 17.2.0
10.13:   xnu-4570.1.46  darwin version 17.0.0
```

So I've deduced that the Major number in Darwin version is unique per OS release :

```
..
16->10.12,
17->10.13, 
18->10.14, 
..
```

Does my assumption is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is correct for major version numbers. Minor versions sometimes increment even if macOS revision doesn't, and vice versa, as in the case of 10.13.1 where the darwin minor version incremented by 1 for a security release, and again for 10.13.1.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is correct. To cover all *OS variants, you'd use:

Let D = Darwin version

MacOS = 10.(D-4) 
TvOS = iOS = (D-6)
WatchOS = (D - 13)

And the minors generally align, unless, as pmdj as noted, there are increments for fixes.

If you want the exact MacOS (or *OS variant) version with minor without guessing, the only place it really "lives" is in /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist. The ProductVersion key (and, in MacOS, the ProductUserVisibleVersion keys are those which get reported in the GUI and elsewhere. The MacOS version number has no real significance anywhere in the OS.